# How to count threads waiting for mutex?

Tags: ruby, concurrency, mutex

Is there a builtin way to count the number of threads waiting for a mutex?

For instance:

```
m= Mutex.new

2.times do
  Thread.new do
    m.lock
  end
end

m.nb_waiting_threads # => 1
```

Comment: Not as far as I can see. Why do you need this? Don't fall for the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no built-in way to count threads waiting on a `Mutex`, but if you can convert your problem to use a `Queue`, there's a [`num_waiting`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Queue.html#method-i-num_waiting) method.

To simulate a `Mutex` with a `Queue`, you would acquire the lock with `pop` and release the lock by `push`ing a value. Your invariant is that the queue only contains 0 or 1 items at any given moment.

```
require 'thread'

semaphore = Queue.new
semaphore.push(1) # Make synchronization token available

threads = []
5.times do |i|
  threads << Thread.new do
    semaphore.pop # Blocks until token available
    puts "Thread #{i} working, #{semaphore.num_waiting} threads waiting."
    sleep rand(3) # Do work
    semaphore.push(1) # Release token
  end
end

threads.each(&:join)
```

```
$ ruby queue_lock.rb
Thread 0 working, 0 threads waiting.
Thread 1 working, 3 threads waiting.
Thread 3 working, 2 threads waiting.
Thread 2 working, 1 threads waiting.
Thread 4 working, 0 threads waiting.
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a nice solution to the problem :)